# How do I change the desktop icon created from a website bookmark?

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts, home-screen, bookmarks

I created a desktop icon from a bookmark for Wikipedia.com.  Here is a screenshot of the result:

[image: screenshot]

The blue background doesn't look great, I'm wondering if this should be transparent.
Here is the image that I think it's using for the wikipedia icon:

[image: apple-touch-icon.png]

Which is being pulled from by this code in wikipedia's page:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="//en.wikipedia.org/apple-touch-icon.png" />
```

The Netflix icon that looks like a banner is a link to Netflix.com, and it has the look I would prefer in the wikipedia icon.

Is there any way I can change the icon?

Comment: FWIW the wikipedia page for that image file http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Wikipedia-mobile-icon.png specifically describes it as "*The Wikipedia "puzzle ball" logo with a blue background*" so I don't think that it is meant to be transparent

Answer (score 3):

Bit of a kludge, but you could create a web page which sends you to Wikipedia and has an icon according to your taste, and bookmark that.

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly convoluted workaround, but you could use my app [Showr](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shadowburst.showr). It lets you add any image to your home screen, and one of the actions it can perform is launching a web page of your choice when clicked.

You could add a Showr widget to your home screen, set it to use any Wikipedia icon of your choice (whether it's already saved to your phone, or by giving it the URL of an icon to download), and set it to launch Wikipedia (in your browser) when clicked. Showr is [a free download from Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shadowburst.showr&referrer=ase17088).